# Bootstrap FLEX unwanted behavior

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

[image]

Hi I am in a legacy code base and somewhere (I have looked everywhere) the flex class is hiding the main div when the window size is less that like 1366 or something. In the image left size is what I want all the time, right side is if the window is smaller than 1366.

I have traces and I ran into bootstrap flex and also an event fires called resize. The legacy code is a mess, I can find in the css where flex is part of the class. All I need to do is to stop hiding the div, show it no matter the window or screen size, but keep all the other functionality.

when I run monitorEvents(window); I get a bunch of these events

resize Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'resize', target: Window, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 2, …}
VM14368:1 resize Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'resize', target: Window, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 2, …}
VM14368:1 resize Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'resize', target: Window, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 2, …}
VM14368:1 resize Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'resize', target: Window, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 2, …}
VM14368:1 resize Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'resize', target: Window, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 2, …}
VM14368:1 resize Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'resize', target: Window, currentTarget: Window, eventPhase: 2, …}

This is the css I beleive is guilty, if I remove display: flex; then the whole page is a mess:

```
.row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 20px;
  --bs-gutter-y: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--bs-gutter-y));
  margin-right: calc(-.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x));
  margin-left: calc(-.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x)); }
  .row > * {
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y); }
```

Comment: I don't really follow the question - what is your specific ask of the StackOverflow community?  It's very unlikely anyone can help you debug your issue with just a screenshot and a small CSS snippet, but honestly I'm not even sure that's what you're asking for.  Can you clarify what you need from us?